# Regular Expression email address Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract top level domains from email addresses with Python.
I want to use a regular expression to get everything after the FIRST dot after the @ symbol

E.g.

```
tony.manero@testing.com
ted.br@top.domain.us
```

Expected result

```
.com
.domain.us
```

How can I use regex to achieve this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this regex and capture group 1 content,

```
@.*?\.(.*)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/D9i0Tn/1)

**Explanation:**

- @.*?. --> Matches @ character followed by any characters in non-greedy way followed by a literal dot
- (.*) --> Capture whatever remains after that which is top level domain name

Here is a sample python code,

```
import re
s = ['tony.manero@testing.com','ted.br@top.domain.us']
for a in s:
    print (a,' --> ',re.findall('@.*?\.(.*)',a))
```

This prints following output,

```
tony.manero@testing.com  -->  ['com']
ted.br@top.domain.us  -->  ['domain.us']
```

Comment: Thank you! what if I'd like to capture everything after the @ symbol, without stopping at the first dot?

Comment: Little change in regex needed and it becomes @(.*)